# Update multiples distros in WSL version 2

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, windows-subsystem-for-linux

HiI want to update using Powershell a powershell script, all the distros found in WSL (version 2)

Unfortunately using this Powershell code, the wsl does not recognize the variable "$distros".

```
 Get a list of installed distributions
# $distributions = wsl.exe --list --quiet

Iterate through each distribution
foreach ($distro in $distributions) {
Write-Host "Updating $distro"

Execute apt-get update and apt-get upgrade within each distribution
wsl.exe --distribution "$distro" -- sudo apt-get update
wsl.exe --distribution "$distro" -- sudo apt-get upgrade -y


also tried using this option, with no effect : error message: A required parameter is missing in the --distribution argument.

Using : wsl.exe --user root --distribution "Ubuntu-Megatron" apt-get update -y works fine 

wsl.exe --user root --distribution "$($distro.Trim())" apt-get update -y
wsl.exe --user root --distribution "$($distro.Trim())" apt-get upgrade -y
```

Comment: The output from wsl --list contains a bunch of whitespace, which is triggering the empty `$distro` variable as part of the loop. I would recommend wrapping the inside of the foreach loop with an `if ($distro)` check, and it _should_ work. IDK about blank spaces within the name of the distros.

Comment: Unfortunately, `wsl.exe`'s output for `--help` and distro-management commands such as `--list` defaults to UTF-16LE, causing PowerShell to mis-decode it.
 The simplest solution is to set `$env:WSL_UTF8=1` beforehand. See the linked duplicate for details.